# How to close a callout for MKAnnotation in a MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a MKMapView that has a number of annotations. Selecting the pin displays the callout and pressing the accessory pops a new viewcontroller onto the stack. However when I press back from that new VC the callout is still open. How do I close it?

I have tried

```
if([[myMapView selectedAnnotations] count] > 0)
{
    //deselect that annotation
    [myMapView deselectAnnotation:[[myMapView selectedAnnotations] objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];
}
```

but this does not work. The selectedAnnotations does have a single entry in the array so it does go into this statement but the callout is not closed.

Do I need to add something to my MKAnnotation implementation or my MKPinAnnotationView?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The objects in selectedAnnotations are instances of MKAnnotation

```
NSArray *selectedAnnotations = mapView.selectedAnnotations;
for(id annotation in selectedAnnotations) {
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if they have changed the SDK since you answered this, but selectedAnnotations are indeed annotations and not instances of MKAnnotationView.

Comment: jowie is right (but I am not sure what the situation was in 2009 when af. replied). I need to write the code like this to make it work: for(id annotation in selectedAnnotations) { 
            [_mapView deselectAnnotation:annotation animated:NO];
        }

Comment: I've only one annotation in [mapView selectedAnnoations ] but callOut is stillVisible

Comment: I needed to also close the callout UIView explicitly, else it wouldn't disappear
`popupView.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 13):

In case you want to stick with the map kit documentation.

```
for (NSObject<MKAnnotation> *annotation in [mapView selectedAnnotations]) {
    [mapView deselectAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Great.   I wanted to autoclose callouts when returning to the map from any other screen except the detail view for that annotation, so I added a variable called cerrarCallout and this method to my view controller         - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { if (cerrarCallout) { for (NSObject<MKAnnotation> *annotation in [self.mapView selectedAnnotations]) { [self.mapView deselectAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation animated:NO]; } }  cerrarCallout = YES; }  Also added   cerrarCallout=YES in viewDidLoad and  cerrarCallout=NO in  the branch of prepareForSegue of the detail view control.

Answer (score 4):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
             calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)
{
    let pin = view.annotation
    mapView.deselectAnnotation(pin, animated: false)
    performSegueWithIdentifier("Next VC Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

Deselect the annotation just before you segue to the new view controller. That way it will be gone when you return.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

Close (deselect) all annotations programmatically...

```
mapView.selectedAnnotations.forEach({ mapView.deselectAnnotation($0, animated: false) })
```

Answer (score 1):

In lieu of a nice solution the following hacky approach works in the viewWillAppear:animated

```
    for( MyMapAnnotation *aMKAnn in  [myMapView annotations])
    {
        //dodgy select then deselect each annotation
        [myMapView selectAnnotation:aMKAnn animated:NO];
        [myMapView deselectAnnotation:aMKAnn animated:NO];
    }
```

the   selectedAnnotations array does have 1 value but deselecting that value still did not close the call out? So I simply iterate through all annotations and select and deselect. I don't have many annotations so probably not too bad a performance hit?

I would appreciate an elegant solution if anyone has better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you reclick the pin the callout should go away...

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)deselectAllAnnotations
{

    NSArray *selectedAnnotations = [self.mapViewObj.mapView selectedAnnotations];
    for (int i = 0; i < [selectedAnnotations count]; i++) {
        [self.mapViewObj.mapView deselectAnnotation:[selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:i] animated:NO];
    }

}
```

This may help you in solving your problem.