# Avoid to display callout when a MKAnnotation is tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to avoid to display a callout when I tap a MKAnnotation, just to display the pin, and when I tap, I want nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: `pin.canShowCallout = NO;` in `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation`

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193928/how-to-close-a-callout-for-mkannotation-in-a-mkmapview

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918154/how-to-hide-mkannotationview-callout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this .

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"sample"];

    annView.canShowCallout = NO;

    return annView;
}
```

Hope this code is useful for you.

Comment: Yes, I was waiting the time limit :P . Thank you, that works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *reuseId = @"pin";
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinV = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (pinV == nil)
    {
        pinV = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        pinV.canShowCallout = NO; // You have to add this.
    }
    return pinV;
}
```